# Modelling social security- and organizationnumber in Organization model

Tags: uml, data-modeling, modeling

I'd want hear your suggestions on how to model a Organization model which could be a private person with social security number or (as in most cases) a company with organization number.
Each organization then have one to many user accounts tied to it.

Any suggestions on clean/lean ways of modelling this?
Right now I'm using following below where Organization is currently Customer:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of model do you want to create? A domain model, meant to describe the real world,  a logical data model or a physical data model?

Comment: I had multiple workshops over many weeks to scratch this topic. In short: this is extremely off topic for SO.

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer. See figure 6 in http://wwwhome.ewi.utwente.nl/~sinderen/publications/pubs_2004/caise2004.pdf

Comment: What you have has logical inconsistencies and is a well known anti pattern.

Comment: @JimL. Wow! Perfect, made it very clear. Thanks for your input :) cheers

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl a logical model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is as follows:

- Abstract base class Organization with concrete subclasses Individual and Company
- Social security number is an attribute of Individual
- Organization number is an attribute of Company
- Class UserAccount
- Association between UserAccount and Customer; multiplicity on UserAccount side: 1..*

Comment: This is not wrong, but it's only one of thousands of possible ways to model it. Once you start arguing here you soon recognize that really everybody can throw in their pound. Person- and Time-related objects are the most complex ones I ever have dealt with.